# How to understand environment details from inside the license file?

Tags: licensing

Inside license file or if you open *Installed licenses* dialogue inside Sitecore's control panel we can see some environment specific details.

Here is a list and values that I'm interested of:

- `Sitecore.Env.CEP.Delivery`: 3
- `Sitecore.Env.CEP.NonProdManagement`: 1
- `Sitecore.Env.Development`: 1
- `Sitecore.Environment`: 6

The `Sitecore.Environment` is 6. However, if we count other values, it gives 5.

How can we understand that values? 
How many servers and what combinations we can install?

Comment: It's incredibly important to understand that the physical license.xml file, does not accurately reflect what may or may not be licensed for. You must refer to the most recent executed Sitecore contract established.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a license for `Sitecore.ContentManager` - this will take you to 6 for the whole environment.

Other counts that can impact the Environment count include:

- `Sitecore.Env.ColdStandby`